# Git stuck at git pull upstream master

Tags: git

I've one commit on my local repository(clone or forked repository) and to pull the changes from the upstream repository, I'm using:

`GIT_TRACE=true git pull upstream master`

it is stuck at

`exec: editor: /src/somepath/.git/MERGE_MSG`

Answer (score 1):

Check your core.editor

```
git config --global core.editor
```

The git pull upstream master get stuck with there is no editor specified, you can specify it as:

```
git config --global core.editor "gedit"
```

Now if you run

```
git pull upstream master
```

For merge message gedit or your specified editor will open the .git/MERGE_MSG file you can add merge message and close it.